# Object to IQueryable

Tags: c#

An API I'm writing always needs an IQueryable as return type, even if it is a single object. This is imposed, I cannot change this. How would I go about creating an IQueryable from an object.

The code I have now feels wrong to me.

```
List<Entity> listOfEntity = new List<Entity>();
listOfEntity.Add(entity);
IQueryable<Entity> queryableEntity = listOfEntity.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Well, unless you created that entity, you got it from somewhere. In that case, why not return the result of your query right away, which will be in `IQueryable` form?

Comment: If you didn't however get the entity from anywhere, then what you have is correct. `IQueryable` can't be manipulated like `IEnumerable`, so you can't add elements directly to it. Your only option is to start with an `IEnumerable` and convert it.

Comment: @stybl: indeed I have the object, not the query unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT (2022): julealgon prompted me to look back on this code after many years, and I have to agree with them that the array initialization isn't necessary. I quickly came up with the code below which can be used as a baseline to implement this yourself.

```
void Main()
{
    var singleValueQueryable = "Foo".ToQueryable();

    foreach (var item in singleValueQueryable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static class ObjectExtensionMethods
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ToQueryable<T>(this T instance)
    {
        return new SingleValueQueryable<T>(instance);
    }
}

public class SingleValueQueryable<T> : IQueryable<T>, IEnumerator<T>
{
    private bool hasExecutedOnce = false;

    public SingleValueQueryable(T value)
    {
        this.Current = value;
    }

    public Type ElementType => typeof(T);

    public Expression Expression => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IQueryProvider Provider => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T Current { get; set; }

    object IEnumerator.Current => this.Current;

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (hasExecutedOnce)
        {
            return false;
        }

        hasExecutedOnce = true;
        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        this.hasExecutedOnce = false;
    }
}
```

Below is a benchmark of the three methods. QueryableMethod is the method shown above. ArrayMethod is the method shown below the benchmark (which was the previous answer). YieldMethod is simply a `yield return` in combination with `AsQueryable()`.

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QueryableMethod | 7.547 ns | 0.1693 ns | 0.1811 ns | 0.0019 | 32 B |
| ArrayMethod | 26.786 ns | 0.2870 ns | 0.2684 ns | 0.0072 | 120 B |
| YieldMethod | 30.609 ns | 0.3935 ns | 0.3680 ns | 0.0062 | 104 B |

---

EDIT (2017): like kienct89 I created a generic extension method for easier use:

```
public static class ObjectExtensionMethods
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ToQueryable<T>(this T instance)
    {
        return new [] {instance}.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

The method can be used simply calling it on the object you created:

```
object anObject = new object();
anObject.ToQueryable();
```

---

> @kienct89: Wow that is almost exactly what I did, even the names
> match, I just took array because it seemed less expensive, you did it
> in one line:
>
> ```
> public static class ObjectExtensionMethods
> {
>     public static IQueryable<T> ToQueryable<T>(this T instance)
>     {
>         TEntityType[] arrayOfObject = {instance};
>         return arrayOfObject.AsQueryable();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> With both our answers I changed it to:
>
> ```
> public static class ObjectExtensionMethods
> {
>     public static IQueryable<T> ToQueryable<T>(this T instance)
>     {
>         return new [] {instance}.AsQueryable();
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: This appears wasteful at first glance. Any suggestions about doing this without having to allocate a new array on every single call?

Comment: @julealgon It's been many years since I wrote this, and at the time I had the same feeling, but I was still a novice in coding. Still a novice now, just a little less. I hope the edited answer can satisfy you.

Comment: That looks like a decent way to start it. One might even want to implement both `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>` in the same class to minimize allocations if that's an issue. I wonder how this compares with a single `yield return` iterator block in terms of allocations though, as that would be quite a bit simpler to implement in combination with `AsQueryable()`.

Comment: @julealgon Very good points! I didn't even think about using `yield return` in combination with `AsQueryable()`. Luckily, I guess, for me, it's around 55% slower on my computer than both solutions above. Combining the `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>` also provided a speed increase for me, which made it around 16% faster on my computer than the array solution.

Comment: @julealgon Added actual benchmark.

Comment: Great stuff. Interesting results there, the difference is quite a bit more significant than I anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need to return `IQueryable`, but I think it's better to create an extension class to convert object to `IQueryable`. That would help to achieve 3 things

1. Easier to update the code in future since you only have to manage the conversion logic in 1 file
2. Less duplicated codes ==> less bugs
3. Easier to test

**Assuming you have 3 model classes**

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class Customer : Entity
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Cart : Entity 
{
}
```

**We can write extension class like this**

```
public static class QueryableExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ToQueryable<T>(this T obj) where T : Entity
    {
        return new List<T> { obj }.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
var customer = new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "test" };
var cart = new Cart { Id = 1 };
IQueryable<Customer> customers = customer.ToQueryable();
IQueryable<Cart> carts = cart.ToQueryable();
```